# resize background image that is scrollable

Tags: css, resize-image

I'm fresh out of school and working on a website that is already developed for the most part. The developer's were marketers and didn't know much about html, css and especially javascript. I'm building a custom page that will mimic a single-page website but I can't seem to make the background images resizble and scrollable. Here is the bit of html and css.

```
<article class="panel_kingdom">
    <section>
        <div class="panel" id="first"></div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="panel" id="second"></div>
    </section>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
.panel {
z-index:50; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
height: 100%; }

.panel_kingdom #first {
background: url(../img_wild/back30_2.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover; }
```

I can specify the position to be absolute or fixed and the image appears but it won't scroll. I can't seem to make the "panels" have a relative position and display without setting a specific pixel height. Any help would be appreciated.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VGHLe/

Comment: A fiddle wouls be awesome http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

instead of cover.

Comment: This distorts the image real bad.

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing you need to specify:

```
display:table
```

### CSS

```
.panel {
position:relative;
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
height: 100%;
    display:table;/*This was needed.*/
}

.panel_kingdom #first {
background: url(http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5532/11710736156_628ce8eba0_s.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover; 
}        
.panel_kingdom #second {
background: url(http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/om-nom.png) no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover; 
}
```

**[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/VGHLe/1/)**

Comment: Works in chrome. Your browser?

Comment: Chrome. It shows when I put text in like you did in fiddle. But I want to be display without anything in the div.

Comment: Let me clear first: you want to assign a static height and width of the `#first` div independent of the content?

Comment: Until and unless a div has any content, no background will be visible. The background will not be visible with no content. You must accept it first. Then only you can think of any logic.

Comment: So basically without any content in the div the background will not be visible.